# Linear model results written to excel file

Tags: r, lm, openxlsx

I'm running a linear model in R and I want the **entire** output of my model to be written to the same excel file.

Right now, I can do this only for the coefficients, which is the first example. The second example is when I try to get the entire output to write to excel, which throws an error on the second to last line of code, see below:

```
# creating data set for lm
df<- cbind.data.frame(var1= rnorm(10,3,2), var2= rnorm(10,4,1))

# running sample model
lmodel<- lm(var1~var2, data = df)

# assigning model results to a variable
mod_res<- summary(lmodel)
mod_res

# assigning model coefficients to a variable
modCoeff<- coef(summary(lmodel))
modCoeff

# getting model coefficients to open in an excel spreadsheet... THIS WORKS!
lmodCoeffs<- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(lmodCoeffs, "coeffs")
openxlsx::writeData(lmodCoeffs, "coeffs", modCoeff, rowNames= TRUE)
openxlsx::openXL(coeffs)

# look at ALL model fit stats in excel... THIS DOES NOT WORK!
modResSheet<- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(modResSheet, "res")
openxlsx::writeData(modResSheet, "res", mod_Res, rowNames= TRUE) # error thrown here
openxlsx::openXL(modResSheet)
```

Getting the coefficients only is useful, however, seeing all model fit stats within one single excel file will make model evaluation more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want on the excel sheet is the output printed when you run `print(mod_res)`, you can use `capture.output`. So the second to last line in your question should be

```
openxlsx::writeData(modResSheet, "res", capture.output(mod_res))
```

For a more tidy layout you can use `tidy` and `glance` from the `broom` package

```
library(broom) #part of tidyverse
openxlsx::writeData(modResSheet, "res", tidy(mod_res)) 
openxlsx::writeData(modResSheet, "res", glance(mod_res),
                    startRow = nrow(tidy(mod_res)) + 4)
```

Comment: this is good but not quite: the format of the data from this is not clean and requires a lot of formatting post-excel writing, whereas the `lmodCoeffs` comes out in clean columns/rows... any idea how to get the format to be cleaner for the full model results?

Comment: I added an option which separates the results into columns/rows.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already received the answer to your original question. I just wanted to add an alternative for convenience sake and other readers that simply want to export their models for further inspection and model evaluation. The package `apaTables` has a function called `apa.reg.table()` that exports the model output table to .doc file in complete APA style formating (even with CIs and semi-partial correlation squared). I find it the most convenient way to do what you are asking (assuming I understood what you are useing it for).

Comment: will it export to `xls`, `xlsx`, or `csv` format as well? or just `doc`? Thanks!

Comment: .rtf or .doc only. It is not the actual solution for what you asked for and I don't supose that modifying the `apa.re.table()` function will be very straight forward in order to export to the wright cells in a excel spreadsheet.